# Add dataframe vector to dataframe table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This should be obvious but I cannot make it work.

I have a pandas dataframe `A` with column and index names:

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[10, 20], [4, 5], [20, 30]], 
                 columns = ['col1', 'col2'], 
                 index = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'])

      col1  col2
row1    10    20
row2     4     5
row3    20    30
```

Then I have another dataframe `B` with only one row (without name, so default 0) and same column names as `A`

```
B = pd.DataFrame([[100, 200]], 
                 columns = ['col1', 'col2'])
      col1  col2
0      100   200
```

I want to add A+B so I obtain a new dataframe `C`:

```
      col1  col2
row1   110   220
row2   104   205
row3   120   230
```

The most obvious thing would be to do:

```
 A + B

      col1  col2
row1   NaN   NaN
row2   NaN   NaN
row3   NaN   NaN
0      NaN   NaN
```

Then I tried

```
A.sum(B)

TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Am I missing something? numpy arrays will do the job super easily, what's wrong with dataframes?

I know the index names don't match, but I want to apply the vector B to all rows of A.

Answer (score 1):

You need create `Series` from `B` by selecting by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or 
[`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and then use [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html):

```
df = A.add(B.iloc[0])
print (df)
      col1  col2
row1   110   220
row2   104   205
row3   120   230
```

Detail:

```
print (B.iloc[0])
col1    100
col2    200
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Or select by index name:

```
df = A.add(B.loc[0])
```

---

```
print (B.loc[0])
col1    100
col2    200
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
In [4472]: A + B.iloc[0]
Out[4472]:
      col1  col2
row1   110   220
row2   104   205
row3   120   230
```